# Nested Stimulus HTML preventing passing values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs, hotwire-rails

With the following I can't access the values in the controller

```html
<div data-controller="static-get-coordinates">
    <div id="sgcmap"
        data-static-get-coordinates-url-value = "<%= url %>"
        data-static-get-coordinates-coords-value = "<%= snippetCoords %>"
        data-static-get-coordinates-center-value = "<%= snippetCenter %>"
        data-static-get-coordinates-xcenter-value = "<%= centerX %>" 
        data-static-get-coordinates-ycenter-value = "<%= centerY %>"
        style="width: 1024px; height: 968px"
        class="mt-1"
    ></div>
    <span>Drawn Coordinates:</span>
    <div id="sgcresult" data-static-get-coordinates-target="drawnCoordinates">
        after drawing a rectangle of course
    </div>
    <div class="fst-italic" data-static-get-coordinates-target="output"></div>
</div> <!-- data-controller div -->
```

but if I unnest it like so the values can be accessed.

```html
<div data-controller="static-get-coordinates" id="sgcmap"
    data-static-get-coordinates-url-value = "<%= url %>"
    data-static-get-coordinates-coords-value = "<%= snippetCoords %>"
    data-static-get-coordinates-center-value = "<%= snippetCenter %>"
    data-static-get-coordinates-xcenter-value = "<%= centerX %>" 
    data-static-get-coordinates-ycenter-value = "<%= centerY %>"
    style="width: 1024px; height: 968px"
    class="mt-1"
></div>
```

I've seen examples of nesting, but it's for targets, not values. Is there a way around this? If I create two like the second, the image that the url refers to is shown twice. (In this example some of the variables (values) aren't being used, but they are in my application, this is a simplified page to work out the problems. This example is available [here](https://rails-openlayers-leaflet.fly.dev/olstaticGetCoords). At the moment it has hard coded "values", but otherwise can draw rectangle and the coordinates appear on the page. The rectangle doesn't stay on the page as it should.

```
// app/javascript/controllers/static_get_coordinates.js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import {getCenter} from 'ol/extent';
import Projection from 'ol/proj/Projection';
import Static from 'ol/source/ImageStatic';
import ImageLayer from 'ol/layer/Image';
import Draw, {createBox} from 'ol/interaction/Draw.js';
import {Vector as VectorSource} from 'ol/source.js';
import {Tile as TileLayer} from 'ol/layer.js';

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ "drawnCoordinates" ]

  static values = {
    url: String,
    coords: Array,
    xcenter: Number,
    ycenter: Number,
    center: Array,
  }
  connect(){
    // var xkcdUrl = this.urlValue;
    // const center = this.centerValue;
   //  var xCenter = this.xcenterValue;
    const source = new VectorSource({wrapX: false});
 
    const extent = [0, 0, 1024, 968];
    const projection = new Projection({
      code: 'xkcd-image',
      units: 'pixels',
      extent: extent,
    });
 
    const xkcdLayer = new ImageLayer({
       source: new Static({
         attributions: '© <a href="https://xkcd.com/license.html">xkcd</a>',
         url: 'https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/online_communities.png',
         // url: xkcdUrl,
         projection: projection,
         imageExtent: extent,
       }),
     });
    var map = new Map({
      layers: [
         xkcdLayer
      ],
      target: 'sgcmap',
      view: new View({
        projection: projection,
        center: getCenter(extent),
        zoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 8,
      }),
    });
    function addDrawInteraction(coordsOutputTarget) {
      let draw = new Draw({
         source: source,
         type: 'Circle', // I think the circle is the cursor
         geometryFunction: createBox(), // this makes the drawn object a rectangle
       });
       map.addInteraction(draw);
   
       draw.on('drawend', function(event) {
         let boxCoords = event.feature.values_.geometry.flatCoordinates; 
         const boxCoordsTrunc = boxCoords.map(x => Math.trunc(x)) // For readabililty truncating the 13 meaningless digits after the decimal place. 
         coordsOutputTarget.textContent = `${boxCoordsTrunc}`;
      }); 
     } 
      addDrawInteraction(this.drawnCoordinatesTarget); // sending target for coordinates and activating the ability to draw a rectangle and get its coordinate
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read and tried myself, you need to write the values on the **controller elements** (the same element where you have your `data-controller` attribute), as stated in the [documentation](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/values). Your controller should only be controlling one instance of *something*, so it shouldn't really matter that you have to put the values in the controller element.

If you're familiar with other JavaScript frameworks such as React or Vue, I guess you could think of a Stimulus controller as something along the lines of a React component: it has some HTML inside it (perhaps some child elements as well) and you can pass it some props (or values in Stimulus) when creating it. The HTML and JavaScript are just split into different files in Stimulus, that's all. Like if you have a `Cart` component, it could have an initial value of `totalSum = 0`. The cart can then have multiple child components, let's call them `CartItems`, which probably take some sort of product as a prop. Adding or removing a `CartItem` (or modifying its properties, such as `quantity`), updates the `Cart` component's `totalSum`.

What I think you need to do here is split up your controller logic in 2 (hard to say exactly without a bit more context, but that's what it looks like). Use the existing one as the outer controller, which could control the existing targets etc. It looks like you're working with some sort of map data, so let's say the inner one only controls an individual map's data: put the values that should be map-specific to each individual map's controller and if there are any values that aren't, assign them to the outer controller. There are various ways you can then send data between these controllers, such as [outlets](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/outlets).

Comment: Thank you for the comments. No familiarity with React or Vue. Rails only and not much good a that (if I understand 5% I'd be surprised). Yes I'm using OpenLayers a mapping library. https://openlayers.org And it bakes in some of what is going on on the page, so it get confusing. I should add the Stimulus controller to the post. I will if I can't sort it out soon (which may be a week since I've got other commitments). And thank you to whoever straightened out the formatting.

Comment: Now working as far as what I originally asked for. The solution is one I thought I tried. It doesn't answer one feature I'd like which is for the target to not be inside the main controller div. But that's the next goal. And maybe I can work around it if it's too much trouble. The field is inside a form with a submit.

Answer (score 0):

Also posted [here at fly.io](https://rails-openlayers-leaflet.fly.dev/olstaticGetCoords)

HTML

```
<div data-controller="static-get-coordinates" id="sgcmap"
    data-static-get-coordinates-url-value = "<%= url %>"
    data-static-get-coordinates-coords-value = "<%= snippetCoords %>"
    data-static-get-coordinates-center-value = "<%= snippetCenter %>"
    data-static-get-coordinates-xcenter-value = "<%= centerX %>" 
    data-static-get-coordinates-ycenter-value = "<%= centerY %>"
    style="width: 1024px; height: 968px"
    class="mt-1">
    <div id="sgcresult" data-static-get-coordinates-target="drawnCoordinates">Drawn coordinates will appear here after drawing a rectangle</div>
</div>
```

// app/javascript/controllers/static_get_coordinates.js

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import {getCenter} from 'ol/extent';
import Projection from 'ol/proj/Projection';
import Static from 'ol/source/ImageStatic';
import ImageLayer from 'ol/layer/Image';
import Draw, {createBox} from 'ol/interaction/Draw.js';
import {Vector as VectorSource} from 'ol/source.js';
import {Tile as TileLayer} from 'ol/layer.js';
    
export default class extends Controller {
    static targets = [ "drawnCoordinates" ]
    
    static values = {
        url: String,
        coords: Array,
        xcenter: Number,
        ycenter: Number,
        center: Array,
    }
    connect(){
        var xkcdUrl = this.urlValue; // this is the only value I'm using in this demo. But other descriptors of the image in the final app
        
        const source = new VectorSource({wrapX: false});
         
        const extent = [0, 0, 1024, 968];
        const projection = new Projection({
            code: 'xkcd-image',
            units: 'pixels',
            extent: extent,
        });
        
        const xkcdLayer = new ImageLayer({
             source: new Static({
                 attributions: '© <a href="https://xkcd.com/license.html">xkcd</a>',
                 url: xkcdUrl,
                projection: projection,
                 imageExtent: extent,
             }),
         });
        var map = new Map({
            layers: [
                 xkcdLayer
            ],
            target: 'sgcmap',
            view: new View({
                projection: projection,
                center: getCenter(extent),
                zoom: 2,
                maxZoom: 8,
            }),
        });
        function addDrawInteraction(coordsOutputTarget) {
            let draw = new Draw({
                 source: source,
                 type: 'Circle',
                 geometryFunction: createBox(),
             });
             map.addInteraction(draw);
             draw.on('drawend', function(event) {
                let boxCoords = event.feature.values_.geometry.flatCoordinates;
                const boxCoordsTrunc = boxCoords.map(x => Math.trunc(x)) // For readability truncating the 13 meaningless digits after the decimal place 
                    coordsOutputTarget.textContent = `${boxCoordsTrunc}`;
            }); 
        }
        addDrawInteraction(this.drawnCoordinatesTarget); // sending target for coordinates and having this function available
     }
}
```